# Not able to connect to socks using http on delegate

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, android, socks-proxy

I have list of socks proxies and and I want to use them on android.
Socks is not directly not supported on android, no luck.
I'm using delegate on a PC.  My phone and PC are on the same network, such that the delegate server on the PC listens for the android phone with HTTP and forwards requests to socks.
I tried using:

```
con32-dg9_9_13 ADMIN="contact@localhost" -P192.168.0.148:1080 SERVER=https SOCKS=socksip:socksport -v
```

and placed my local IP as a proxy on phone, still, on the phone I'm only able to use local internet, not the proxied one.  I checked using "what is my IP" on phone it shows my original IP, not the socks server IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Default is socksV5 and it require auth
- for socksV4 use /-4 after socks ip:port
- Example:

  `con32-dg9_9_13 ADMIN="contact@localhost" -P192.168.0.148:1080 SERVER=https SOCKS=socksip:socksport/-4 -v`